# Django url slash matching

Tags: python, regex, django

my url pattern in apps like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_1),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_2),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg3>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_3),
]
```

the url : `/show/in_arg1/in_arg2%2F_this_is_arg2` match to view_3
but I want to let the url match view_2

I try to change urlpatterns like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_1),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.\/]+)$', views.view_2),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.\/]+)/(?P<arg3>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_3),
]
```

the url : `/show/in_arg1/in_arg2%2F_this_is_arg2` works well

but the url `/show/in_arg1/in_arg2/in_arg3` will match to view_2, not what I want

It seems django decode %2F to / before url matching

Can I let django do url matching without decode %2F ?

Or some way to solve my problem

thanks

Comment: Add `regex` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `\/`in `(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.\/]+)` that's messing you up. They would even match `show/a//b`!
Try these:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_1),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_2),
    url(r'^show/(?P<arg1>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg2>[\w\d_\.]+)/(?P<arg3>[\w\d_\.]+)$', views.view_3),
]
```

Somebody more savvy in regex might help you further.